# Klondike private NuGet repository api page responds with an HTTP 404.0 error

Tags: iis, nuget

Using the instructions in this [link](https://dotnetthoughts.net/building-a-private-nuget-repository-using-klondike/) and the "How to Deploy Klondike"
 [github](https://github.com/themotleyfool/Klondike#how-to-deploy-klondike) instructions I have installed the Klondike release on my local IIS (Version 10.0.15063.0).  At first it looked promising, but then I realized that the main page is showing "loading..." rather than the Klondike URL.  See image: [image: site root image]

Additionally the when I click the API page tab, the site navigates to `http://localhost:8081/api` which returns a 404.0 HTTP error.  This error may not seem very surprising as the site's directory does not contain an api directory.  However, I have reverse engineering a working server with Klondike configured on it and it also does not have the api directory.  Here is an image of the 404.0 error: [image]

Additionally, when I try to `nuget push`to localhost:8081, it results with the error in the image here (note, the red blocked out text is the apikey). [image: error on cmd line]

Finally, I have left the `handleLocalRequestsAsAdmin` is set to true, but even though I am on localhost, it does not show me the "LocalAdministrator" link.  I believe that all these symptoms are linked to the same issue.

I have tried the following with no affect on the behavior:

1. Putting this site in `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` and also in `C:\Klondike`;
2. Using different port numbers, such as 8081 and 80;
3. Putting a `127.0.0.1` alias in my `hosts` file and binding the value in IIS to the host name; and
4. Installed the [Debugging tools for Windows](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/download-windbg) install as was suggested on the github site and set the `debuggingToolsPath` to its path.

(at this point, I'm just guessing at the issue)

The settings I have changed in `settings.config` file are as follows:

1. `packagesPath` = `C:\Klondike\App_Data\Packages`
2. Left `lucenePath` = empty string (I also tried this with a value of `C:\Klondike\App_Data\Lucene` with no affect.
3. `symbolsPath` = `C:\Klondike\App_Data\Symbols`
4. `debuggingToolsPath` = `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64`
5. `ignorePackageFiles` = "true"

I have not changed any values in the `web.config` file from the default web.config release values.

Thank you for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, although I was installing Klondike on a remote server rather than locally, but still IIS 10. The problem might be you don't have all the IIS components installed or enabled. More specifically, .NET or one of its required components might not be installed or enabled. If you look at the error on the /api link - it has to do with the MapRequestHandler and Static file handler in IIS - this indicates IIS doesn't know how to handle the request, which is an indicator you might be missing the ExtensionlessUrlHandler in IIS, as well as other components. To solve the problem, go to Start -> Control Panel -> Turn Windows features on or off (varies per system, might be under "Programs and Features"), then find the IIS Application Development Features. These might be listed under Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services, or Web Server (IIS) -> Web Server, depending on your system. Once you find these Application Development Features, make sure you have an ASP.NET option checked - you might just want to check all the options. Below is screenshot of what it looks like on my system. You might want to reboot after adding those features - not sure if a reboot is required, but it doesn't hurt. After you enable those features, you might start to run into all kinds of file permission errors when running the Klondike app - you might want to just remove Klondike and reinstall it from the zip file. I have a feeling it Klondike doesn't run cleanly the first time it has problems, as it needs to create an App_Data folder with sub directories.
[image: Application Development Features]

Comment: el-kammino, this worked, you made my weekend! 

For future solution finders, here's what fixed it:
**1** Start > Control Panel>Programs and Features>Turn Windows features on or off
**2** Ensure following are checked: (.NET Extensibility 4.X, ASP.NET 4.X, ISAPI Extensions, ISAPI Filters)
**3** Delete * from the C:\Klondike directory (or whereever your iis files are)
**4** Copy the [build version](https://github.com/themotleyfool/Klondike/releases) of Klondike into the C:\Klondike directory
**5** Change the Settings.config file as needed.
**6** Reboot machine (just for good measure)